Invalid address in C
I ran a program like this
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

(*$$)() = 0x7ffff7e9a870;
$(){
    $$(1, "Hello, World!\n", 14);
}

0x7ffff7e9a870 comes from another program or I performed:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p\n", write);
    printf("%p\n", &write);
}

With aslr disabled (so I have /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space = 0)
if I compile my program with
$ gcc -B/usr/bin -Wl,--entry=$ -nostartfiles -w -O3 -g3 -o bin notmain.c

All he's ok but if I launch it:
$ ./bin 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And if I run my program with gdb I have this weird output:
pwndbg> b * '$'
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000: file notmain.c, line 5.
pwndbg> r
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/bin 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055792b67be33 in ?? ()
LEGEND: STACK | HEAP | CODE | DATA | WX | RODATA
───────────────────────────────────────────────[ REGISTERS / show-flags off / show-compact-regs off ]───────────────────────────────────────────────
 RAX  0x1c
 RBX  0
 RCX  0x7fffffffdd48 —▸ 0x7fffffffdff4 ◂— 'SHELL=/bin/bash'
 RDX  0x7ffff7fc9040 ◂— endbr64
 RDI  0x7ffff7ffe2e0 —▸ 0x555555554000 ◂— 0x10102464c457f
 RSI  0x7ffff7ffe888 ◂— 0
 R8   0
 R9   0
 R10  0x555555554000 ◂— 0x10102464c457f
 R11  0
 R12  0x55792b67be33
 R13  0x7fffffffdd30 ◂— 1
 R14  0
 R15  0
 RBP  0
 RSP  0x7fffffffdd30 ◂— 1
 RIP  0x55792b67be33
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM / x86-64 / set emulate on ]────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Invalid address 0x55792b67be33










─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ STACK ]──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
00:0000│ r13 rsp 0x7fffffffdd30 ◂— 1
01:0008│         0x7fffffffdd38 —▸ 0x7fffffffdfae ◂— '/mnt/c/Users/bin'
02:0010│         0x7fffffffdd40 ◂— 0
03:0018│ rcx     0x7fffffffdd48 —▸ 0x7fffffffdff4 ◂— 'SHELL=/bin/bash'
04:0020│         0x7fffffffdd50 —▸ 0x7fffffffe004 ◂— 'WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED=1'
05:0028│         0x7fffffffdd58 —▸ 0x7fffffffe01c ◂— 'WSL_DISTRO_NAME=Ubuntu-22.04'
06:0030│         0x7fffffffdd60 —▸ 0x7fffffffe039 ◂— 'NAME=DESKTOP-PH516IR'
07:0038│         0x7fffffffdd68 —▸ 0x7fffffffe04e ◂— 'PWD=/mnt/c/Users/'
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ BACKTRACE ]────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ► 0   0x55792b67be33 None
   1              0x1 None
   2   0x7fffffffdfae None
   3              0x0 None
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

The same problem comes when I do a program just right this:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

(*$$)();
$(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("%p\n", write);
}

$ gcc -B/usr/bin -Wl,--entry=$ -nostartfiles -w -O3 -g3 -o b
in notmain.c
$ valgrind ./bin
==5537== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5537== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5537== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5537== Command: ./bin
==5537==
Hello World
==5537== 
==5537== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5537==  General Protection Fault
==5537==    at 0x48DC0D0: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1244)
==5537==    by 0x499BC4A: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:33)
==5537==
==5537== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5537==     in use at exit: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==5537==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==5537==
==5537== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5537==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5537==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5537==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5537==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==5537==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5537== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5537==
==5537== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==5537== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The first one is executed but... not the second.
Can someone help me ? Thank you !

The C runtime library is normally dynamically linked, so I don't think you can assume that write will have the same address.

@Barmar I disable the randomisation on my system

@Asile34, printf(“%p\n”, write); is suspicious.  Does true code use smart quotes or "?

@chux oups bad copy past sorry is "

any reason for using $s? Do  hackers use $s? You code invokes UB as $$ and $ have to return int

@0___________ I try to create a c code without any letter :)

%p expects void * but you pass pointer to a function. It's UB.

Actually on my system (x86_64) your program compiled with -Wno-implicit-int -Wno-int-conversionand with ASLR disabled prints "Hello, World!" before Segmentation fault.

@dimich yeah of course me too !

@Asile34 So what is your question? Why does Segmentation fault happen when _start returns while it is not supposed to return?

@dimich why the first printf is ok but the second is crashed

@Asile34 You are calling C library functions without C runtime initialized.

The fact you disabled randomization means one program will have the same addresses evert time, if it executes the same actions with regard to loading dynamic libraries and otherwise allocating memory. It does not mean a different program will have the same addresses. When one program links to some routines (like printf) that the other does not, their memory layouts may differ.

The start routine should not return. Nothing sets return address is passed to it. It should call a system routine to end execution. Returning is likely to cause a segment fault.

@0___________: The C standard does not require a routine declared to return a value to return a value.

@dimich: write is not a standard C library routine.

Since there is no reference to write in your program, the linker does not link it into the executable.

"I try to create a c code without any letter :)" is poking a finger in your eye not hurting enough? ;)

@EricPostpischil I mean printf(), not write() (explaining why the first printf is ok but the second is crashed). However, I don't know whether it really crashes in second printf(), but definetely crashes after attempt to return from $ which is not called as a function.

I never said anything about randomization, I said dynamic linking.
